# How Can I set the intent of a service in android to a shared page in Xamarin cross platform

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I am trying to set the return page of an android notification to a content page in Xamarin. That is, an android service sends a local notification and when the user clicks on the notification, he is taken to a shared xamarin.forms page.

In the code below, "MyWishList"

is a shared page in the PCL but the code resides in the Android version of the project. Running this code throws an exception

> System.ArgumentException: type
>   Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type.

It works fine when I change MyWishList to an android activity, but I need to connect the notification to a shared page.

```
void sendUserNotification(string title, string username)
    {
        // Pass the current button press count value to the next activity:
        Bundle userDetails = new Bundle();
        userDetails.PutString(title, username);

        // When the user clicks the notification, SecondActivity will start up.
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyWishList)); // change mainActivity to wishlist page pcl

        // Pass some values to SecondActivity:
        resultIntent.PutExtras(userDetails);

        // Construct a back stack for cross-task navigation:
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

        // Create the PendingIntent with the back stack:            
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        // Build the notification:
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)                    // Dismiss from the notif. area when clicked
            .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)  // Start 2nd activity when the intent is clicked.
            .SetContentTitle("New Notification: " + counter)      // Set its title
             .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.zaposta_icon);  // Display this icon


        // Finally, publish the notification:
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder.Build());
    }
```

Comment: Did you got any solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Probably your "MyWishList" activity is the ViewModel. I set the View and I solved it.

I hope this could help others with the same problem.